# Calendar Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Using this calendar tool here, http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/.

I am getting an issue inside calendar.js on this line of code:

```
 Calendar.prototype._loadTemplate = function (name) {

    if (this.options.templates[name]) {
        return;
    }

    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:      self._templatePath(name),
        dataType: 'html',
        type:     'GET',
        async:    false,
        cache:    this.options.tmpl_cache
    }).done(function (html) {
        self.options.templates[name] = _.template(html);
    });
};
```

> The browser is throwing 'Failed to load resource: the server responded
>   with a status of 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)

The strange thing is that I dont get any error on my local machine, but I only get error when running this code via server (IIS).

Even on server, this error is not shown always. It comes randomly whenever I refresh the page.

Any idea, whats the issue?

Comment: 500 error means server side error, please check the page you have given into url of ajax call. or use inspect element of browser to check it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have googled it and all i found was that it is an issue on IIS server side. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out there was some port forwarding issue on IIS Server, I was using host name on the URL like www.tilda.com, I replaced it with the actual URL of the server and now I am not getting any issue.

Thanks.